# some questions on spin group

Tags: spin-geometry

The spin  group of an inner product space $V$ is defined  in terms  of  the Clifford  algebra of $V$,  which  is  spanned  by  products of vectors in $V$. Does  any vector  in $V$ correspond to a reflection in the normal  sense? How can we explain  the relation  $\left<u, v\right> + \left<v, u\right> = 2g(u, v)$ in  the  definition  of  the Clifford  algebra geometrically?

Comment: See section 2.1 of [these notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/DiracNotes.pdf) by Dan Freed.